# Ignore internal linkage (static declaration) and call a function anyway?

Tags: c, linker, clang

I am trying to debug someone else's library. While not in the header, the library includes a C-style symbol `_library_internal_function` which I would like to use from what is essentially a test harness.

In many cases when I'm missing a header, I can sort of "make my own" using `extern`:

```
extern int library_internal_function(int);

int test_library_function() {
   return library_internal_function(42);
}
```

However in this case, I get an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_library_internal_function", referenced from:
      _test_library_function in MyCode.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I believe the internal function must have been declared as `static int library_internal_function(int)` i.e. has internal linkage. So I would *expect* this error.

But I'm wondering if there's a way to override this somehow, and circumvent the original linkage option. The symbol is definitely there in the library (it didn't get inlined or optimized away); can I somehow force clang's linker to find and use the internal function anyway?

To reiterate: this is not production code. I'm just trying to debug something and it would be really helpful if I could call the function directly, myself, instead of in a roundabout way via the public API of the "victim" library.

Comment: If the function you are attempting to call is static, you cannot call it by name unless you are ready to write a fair chunk of a debugger.  If you can get a pointer to, you can use that, but it usually requires cooperation from the library.  If you have the source to the library (chalk one up for open source!) then you have more options of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I actually do have most of the source code, but am unable to compile it myself (the library author's project has some complicated dependencies and seems to be missing a few private files, etc.). I can see the function's  name in a disassembler — so that "metadata" must still exist. Why can't `ld` find it? I could try deriving its address based on the nearest external symbol in the library, I suppose…

Comment: Even if you can't compile the whole library, can you compile the one file containing the function that you're worried about?  It's annoying if you can't compile the source — it makes it an odd sort of open source if that's what it is.  If you can't compile the one file, then can you contact the author for guidance?  One thing to consider is whether there's an alternative function that does the job?